# Clickable area of menu items in SplitActionBar Android

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I Googled a lot but didn't find the solution for this task. I even think that it is not possible to acoplish, but before I make this as my final conclusion I had to ask you guys.

So basically, the problem that I'm trying to solve is best described with an example. I have been working on Android 4.0 ICS. I used SplitActionBar to display menu items. And everything is worked fine. I have only two items in SplitActionBar and they are positioned on the right and on the left side of ActionBar. The middle area is empty. You can only click on small area around menu item icons. What I want is to have those two menu items occupy entire split action bar area. Like two buttons or if it describes better like menus were in previous Android.

Thanks a lot guys, I know that ICS is pretty new so I would appreciate any help that I could get.

Nebojsa